# Break in While Loop when Specific Input is Entered

Tags: ruby, compare, ruby-2.0

I am trying to halt input from a user when their input is 42.

The correct answer on the website I'm working on is:

```
while line = gets   
  break if (/42/ =~ line)
  x << line 
end
```

The code I tried that does not work is:

```
while line = gets.chomp
  break if (line == 42)
  x << line 
end
```

Why is this the case? Am I missing some limitations to what I can use in my `if` statement?

Comment: Since you're a novice this won't be much help, but note Ruby is a language that declarative code is possible thanks to blocks. I think something like this is pretty neat: `lines = repeat { gets }.take_while { |line| line.strip != "42" }` (fill the blanks for missing methods ;-))

Comment: Thanks!  So obvious & under my nose.  I somehow assumed Ruby would magically recognize the 42 as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that 42 is an integer, but `line` is a string:

```
1.9.3p392 :001 > "42" == 42
 => false
```

So it's never the case that your if statement is getting triggered, because it's comparing two different kinds of things. Matching with a Regex fixes it, though it's looking for "42" to appear anywhere in the input (e.g. "3427"). I think what you meant to say was

```
while line = gets.chomp
    break if (line == "42")
    x << line 
end
```

In other words, break when the input is a string with the characters 4 and 2 in it.

Comment: note that `gets` returns the carriage return. Maybe `line.chomp == "42"`?

Comment: @tokland The OP's code already has the chomp, but I've edited my answer to include the full code block, just for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

`<<` is a method(`Append`) on `Array` or `String` class objects. But your  `x` not holding any referencing to such objects. Thus you are getting `undefined local variable or method 'x' for main:Object (NameError)`.

Try this instead(by fixing local variable `x` to hold a practical object and converting `line` value to `Fixnum` object:

```
x = "hi"
while line = gets.chomp
  break if (line.to_i == 42)
  x << line 
end
```

This program will help you `to halt input from a user when their input is 42`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because you're comparing a number to a string.  The example uses a regular expression it appears.  "42" == 42 will give you false in ruby.

Answer (score 0):

```
until (line = gets.chomp).to_i == 42   
  x << line 
end
```

This of course bypasses the if statement you were asking about.

Your limitation for the if is based solely on the fact that you are comparing a string that will always be a string to a number, and this will never be equal.  (as others have mentioned)

So we must reconsider the conditional statement.  In this case, I considered it "out of place" and moved the comparison to the 'while' loop, and then inverted it to an 'until' statement, to be able to positively express the condition to end the loop on.  Whenever I see a 'break' in a loop, I try to get rid of that smell, as the condition to leave a loop should really be expressed in the loop condition if possible.

I hope this helps.